# How to pass a session befor routing with iron:router on meteor?

Tags: node.js, meteor, session-variables, iron-router

In my post_item.html I got this line:

```
 <a href="{{pathFor 'postPage' _id=this._id}}" class="discuss btn">Discuss</a>
```

In my router.js:

```
  Router.map(function() {
    this.route('postPage',{path:'/posts/:_id',
    beforeRoutingTo: function(id) {
        console.log("hello!");
       Session.set('currentPostId', id); 
    }
  });
  });
```

In my post_page.js

```
Template.postPage.helpers({
     currentPost: function() {
     return Posts.findOne(Session.get('currentPostId'));
     }
});
```

In my post_page.html

```
<template name="postPage">
 {{#with currentPost}}
 {{> postItem}}
 {{/with}}
</template>
```

What am I doing wrong?
How can I pass the ID to the new 'page' and show the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're working on the meteor tutorial using the book 'Discover Meteor'. I faced the same issue, however, I was able to solve it without using session. You don't need any helpers anymore, if you use [iron router](https://atmospherejs.com/iron/router).

client/router.js:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('/post/:_id', function () {
      var item = Posts.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
      this.render('postItem', {data: item});
    },
    {
      name: 'post.show'
    });
});
```

client/posts/post_item.html

```
<a href="{{pathFor route='post.show'}}" class="discuss btn">Discuss</a>
```

as you see, in the `router.js` the id is parsed from the url. Also, we name the `/post/:id` route after ***'posts.show'*** and we can get the url from the view referencing that name: `{{pathFor route='post.show'}}`

Comment: WOW! that really worked! I tried this for a long time with many different types... 
I would like do it more this way, but it doesnt work: 
`Router.route('/post/:_id', {
  name: 'postPage',
  data: function() {
    return
  Posts.findOne(this.params._id); }
});`

in post_item.html:
`<a href="{{pathFor 'postPage'}}" class="discuss btn">Discuss</a>`

And in post_page.html

`<template name="postPage">
  <div class="post-page page">  
    {{> postItem}}
  </div>
</template>`

Comment: just in the case I want show more than only the Item, I need the post_page.html for adding more details to that clicked Item.
I have only the old book 'discover meteor' - I saw this version of the book (in german) - http://de.discovermeteor.com/chapters/routing/

Comment: OK thx! I tested your code a little bit and changed it to: 
route.js:

   `this.route('/post/:_id', function () {
      var item = Posts.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
      this.render('postPage', {data: item});
    },
    {
      name: 'postPage'
    });`
in post_item.html the discuss link:
 `<a href="{{pathFor 'postPage'}}" class="discuss btn">Discuss</a>`
in post_page.html I can add more Details: 

`<template name="postPage">
  <div class="post-page page">  
    {{> postItem}}
    mooore details goes here! thx Ronin!
  </div>
</template>`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you need a session for this, but your route looks wrong. Try the below:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('postPage',{path:'/posts/:_id',
    onBeforeAction: function() {
        console.log("hello!");
       Session.set('currentPostId', this.params._id); 
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: it's `this.params._id`